# Control spring bean scope based on the user login

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication

I want to create a new bean when ever a new user login so that it will be cached for the entire user sesion. Currently im using the scope as prototype, which is creating a new bean for every request. Is there a way to control the scope of the bean based on the username?

My bean has methods which does some recursive opertations. Now since my bean is prototype, these recursive calls are making my application slow. I do not want a singleton bean, because the result of these recursive calls depends on the username and user access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use session scope.

For example:

@Bean

@SessionScope (or @Scope(value = "session"))

You can check all available scopes at:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: I tried this, but if another user logs in, the old bean is still available. That is why i used prototype.